# Issue with rendering component

Tags: reactjs

I have component where i want to search for a list of users. The issue that i am having is that my this.state.employees is not called before render. I am using the componentDidMount to get my list of employees, see below:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    if (!!this.props.employees && this.props.employees.length == 0) {
       this.props.listEmployees();
      }
    }
```

So at the moment by component is returning no employees. Does anyone know the best way of doing this.

```
class ShareForUsers extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      props,
      menuOpen: false,
      value: "",
      values: []
    };
  }

    componentDidMount() {
    if (!!this.props.employees && this.props.employees.length == 0) {
       this.props.listEmployees();
      }
    }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ ...nextProps })
  }
  render() {
    if (!!this.state.employees) return <p>no employees</p>;
    console.log(this.state.employees)
    return (
      <div>
         {persons}
        {this.renderUsers}
        <TextField
          fullWidth
          value={this.state.value}
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: this.state.values
              .concat()
              .sort(({ label: aLabel }, { label: bLabel }) => {
                if (aLabel < bLabel) return -1;
                else if (aLabel > bLabel) return 1;
                return 0;
              })
              .map(chip => (
                <InputAdornment
                  component={Chip}
                  label={chip.label}
                  onDelete={() => {
                    const value = chip;
                    this.setState(({ values: prevValues }) => {
                      const values = prevValues;
                      const idx = values.indexOf(value);
                      if (idx === -1) {
                        values.push(value);
                      } else {
                        values.splice(idx, 1);
                      }

                      return {
                        values
                      };
                    });
                  }}
                />
              ))
          }}
          onChange={evt => {
            const value = evt.target.value;
            this.setState({
              value,
              menuOpen: value.length > 0
            });
          }}
          onFocus={() =>
            this.setState(({ value }) => ({
              menuOpen: value.length > 0
            }))
          }
          onBlur={() => this.setState({})}
        />
        <div>
          {this.state.menuOpen ? (
            <Paper
              style={{
                position: "absolute",
                zIndex: 100,
                width: "100%"
              }}
            >
            {this.state.employees
                .filter(
                  employee =>
                  employee.user.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.value) > -1
                )
                .map(employee => (
                  <MenuItem
                    key={employee.value}
                    onClick={() => {
                      this.setState(({ values: prevValues }) => {
                        const values = prevValues.concat();
                        const idx = values.indexOf(employee);
                        if (idx === -1) {
                          values.push(employee);
                        } else {
                          values.splice(idx, 1);
                        }

                        return {
                          values,
                          value: "",
                          menuOpen: false
                        };
                      });
                    }}
                  >
                    {employee.label}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
            </Paper>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const shareForUsers = withStyles(styles)(ShareForUsers)
export default connect(
  state => state.user,
  dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
)(shareForUsers);
```

Comment: can you remove the if condition, keep only this.props.listEmployess() in componentDidMount method and check if its working fine

Comment: no that didnt help.

Comment: Is it receiving any data? console.log in   componentWillReceiveProps()

Comment: when i do that the employees array is empty

Comment: Then probably problem is with fn passed as listEmployes in parent. In browser/network tab can you see request and valid response?

Comment: i am getting a valid response from the backend

Comment: i thought that the issue was that render happens before ComponentDidMount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to keep the `employees` in your state. You can still use the `this.props.employees` in your render method.

Be especially wary of the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method, it has been marked for removal in future release of React. It was enabling many anti-patterns in eyes of React community, so they provided a replacement lifecycle `getDerivedStateFromProps`. I highly recommend reading the [official blog post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) on this lifecycle method.

Some notes on your code:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      props,
      menuOpen: false,
      value: "",
      values: []
    };
}
```

**Note 1:**

You are putting the "props" in your state. 
This is absolutely not necessary. Wherever you need to access state, you will also have access to props. So, no benefit of putting it inside your state and potential downsides of unwanted/unexpected state changes because an unrelated prop is changing.

**Note 2:**

Bad initial state. If you really need (for some reason), to have `employees` in your state. Then you must initialize them properly in the constructor.

**Note 3:**

You're missing a feedback for the user that you are "loading/fetching" the data. As of now, when you render, first a user will see: *No Employees Found* and then when data has been fetched, they will magically see the screen.

If your flow was "synchronous" in nature, it might have been ok, but you are having an async behaviour, so you must also prepare for following **states** of your component:

> Loading|Error|Loaded(No Data)|Loaded(data found)